# remove rows which contain special character like '/' in pyspark or pysql

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have data contains column A

```
A
107/108
105
103
103/104
```

Output should be like:-

```
105
103
```

I have tried lot with filter function in pyspark and also in pysql even but code doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either **`rlike,like,contains`** functions with **`negation (~)`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('107/108',),('105',),('103',),('103/104',)],['A'])
df.show()
#+-------+
#|      A|
#+-------+
#|107/108|
#|    105|
#|    103|
#|103/104|
#+-------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
#using rlike function
df.filter(~col("A").rlike("\/")).show()

#using like function
df.filter(~col("A").like("%/%")).show()

#using contains function
df.filter(~col("A").contains("/")).show()
#+---+
#|  A|
#+---+
#|105|
#|103|
#+---+
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('107/108',),('105',),('103',),('103/104',),('',)],['A'])
df.show()
#+-------+
#|      A|
#+-------+
#|107/108|
#|    105|
#|    103|
#|103/104|
#|       |
#+-------+

df.filter(~col("A").rlike("\/")).show()
df.filter(~col("A").like("%/%")).show()
df.filter(~col("A").contains("/")).show()
#+---+
#|  A|
#+---+
#|105|
#|103|
#|   |
#+---+
```

Comment: while executing it is giving me an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: Hi while validating the data your expression also removes blank rows as well so is there any other way around?

Comment: @codetech, I updated the answer with blank row test case and expression is not removing blank rows..!